# Sass files loaded from non-existent directory on apache server?

Tags: css, sass

I've not used sass before, this website was built by someone else who I can no longer get hold of. It worked as soon as copied the directory onto my server though, and I hadn't set up anything sass related in apache. (debian 8)

When I f12 in chrome, I can see that some css settings come from a file called "source/_global.sass". There is no "source" directory in my website's root though, and no "source" alias set up in apache. There is a "sass" directory that has a _global.sass file in it though, but when I make the required changes to this file, they don't show up on the website. I have "disable cache" enabled in web dev tools.

In chrome developer tools I open the global.sass file in a new tab, and it gives me a 404.

I can't actually see anywhere in the html that is loading the sass files either. Can anyone suggest what I might need to do to make the modifications I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Sass files are usually not uploaded to the server, what you see is the original mapped path from the sass compilation that happened offline. See http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass to get a better understanding of map files.

Comment: thanks, for some reason it won't let me enter comments under 15 chars

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on @Capsule's comment, the problem was simply that I didn't know about sass source mapping which chrome & firefox web dev tools use to tell you where the particular piece of css is from in the sass source code, instead of where it actually is on the server, which is in the compiled .css file.

So if someone else is as ignorant as me, forget the source folder, that only exists in your browser tools. You need to edit the sass and recompile it to get your new .css file.